# Error handling in stored procedures

Tags: sql-server-2008, error-handling

I have a single "Pre-Processing" Stored procedure which calls multiple stored procedures inside.

Finally when all my SPS (inside) have successfully executed, I want to run an update statment, so in the main SP I have :

```
EXEC SP1
EXEC SP2
EXEC SP3

-- RUN UPDATE statment here
```

All of my inner SPs have the following template :

```
  BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRANSACTION

  // DO SOME INSERT,UPDATE ETC..

  COMMIT TRANSACTION;
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
         SELECT 
            ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
            ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
            ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
            ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
            ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
            ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;

  IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
         RETURN
  END CATCH
```

My question is as to what is the best approach for error handling in this scenario, i.e. I want to make sure everything got done before I run that final update statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing this since I figured out that each SP had to have its own Error handling and the outside SP calling multiple SPs would not need to have error handling.